# Caddy server:multiple proxies for same site

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, caddy, caddyfile

I'm using Caddy to revers proxy some sites on a DigitalOcean Ubuntu droplet.

This is my Caddy file, pretty simple :upside_down:

```
my-site.com {
  # projects
  proxy /projects/some-project localhost:8998

  # main site
  proxy / localhost:9000
}

other-site.com {
  proxy / localhost:8999 # main site
}
```

`my-site.com` and `other-site.com` are working just fine.

But I'm getting a 404 when trying to access `my-site.com/projects/some-project`. I've double checked and `localhost:8998` works properly on DO.

`my-site.com` is a [Harp.js](https://harpjs.com/) app, it is catching all the 404 how it is expected, but `/projects/some-project` is showing the Caddy default 404 message.

Should I work like I expect? Am I missing something?

*The question is also posted on the [Caddy forum](https://forum.caddyserver.com/t/multiple-proxies-for-same-site/667).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question was answered in the Caddy forum.

My `localhost:8998` expects that path to be its root so the solution was:

```
without /projects/some-project
```